# Does gluLookAt add or set the view matrix variables?

Tags: opengl, camera

I'm trying to rotate the camera view in PyOpenGL, but it's not working well. The weirdest behavior I've noticed is that putting gluLookAt in a loop seems to change the camera view, even when I'm not changing the inputs as the loop continues.

So while I'd expect something like:

```
gluLookAt(0,0,0, 0,0,-5, 0,0,1)
```

to keep the camera constantly pointing downwards, it seems to rotate the view in some strange way, with the objects being rendered leaving the maximum clipping radius after a while.

My question is, does gluLookAt take into account the previous camera settings, or do I need to look for something else wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GluLookAt_code

gluLookAt computes a matrix and multiplies it with the current matrix. You need to use glLoadIdentity before using gluLookAt, in other words.